# Mechanism to temporarily connect different pitch stake pins (2.54mm and 1.27mm)?

Tags: connector

I'm working with boards that have a mix of pin pitch and occasionally I need to connect a 2.54mm pin to a 1.27mm pin.  The most recent example was to get access to UART output that was being provided via 1.27mm but my USB-to-UART adapter has 2.54mm.  Soldering would work but I'd prefer something more temporary that I can quickly connect/disconnect.

(This is my first post to this community so feel free to edit the post/tags and give me a nudge in a better direction if I'm off track.)

Comment: Make an adapter? Like in PCB or a cable with two connectors matching both sides.

Comment: @EugeneSh.I wish I could get connectors matching both sides but I haven't been able to find any single-connector 1.27mm female connectors.  Surely they exist somewhere but darned if I can find them.

Comment: IC test hooks for very temporary uses? e.g. sparkfun makes https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9741 IC test hooks with 2.54mm male pins on the other end, or you can solder your own

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to approach the problem, but what I would do (and I do), is to keep some male/female headers with a 1.27mm and 2.54mm pitch always in the drawer together with some wirewrap wire. In that way, when the issue comes up, it doesn't take long to create a bridge cable to convert from one pitch/pinout to the other.

With a bit of practice, it is not too hard to solder on a 1.27mm connector.

Answer (score 1):

Many hobby shops sell patch cables also called jumper cables. They come in various lengths and bundles. The picture below shows a bundle of 40 female-female cables. You can make sets of one, two or more cables by pulling them apart.

I found they fit most header pins.

[image]

Comment: I have a variety of these actually (M-M, M-F, F-F) but they are all 2.54mm pitch and just too huge to use on the 1.27mm pins which are super-tiny.  I haven't been able to find *any* single-connector 1.27mm female jumper wires.  Would be great if I could!